# Scout - Compiling SASS ArgumentError

Tags: ruby, sass, jruby

while compiling my Sass file with the ScoutApp I recieve the following error message:

```
ArgumentError on line 2104 of org/jruby/RubyKernel.java: wrong number of arguments (4 for 3)
```

This just suddenly happend. I haven't changed anything on my system and I really don't know what to do about it. The reinstallation of Scout lead to the same results.
Any suggestions for a solution?

Regards,
Nils

Answer (score 1):

After trying a few things I found the answer myself. If anyone has the same problem here is what caused the trouble for me:

Somewhere in my sass file I had the following declaration

```
background: rgb(0,0,0,0.75);
```

Which is of course invalid and must be:

```
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

The missing letter really gave me some headache. Especially because I was expecting an error message sass usually throws out in the compiled css file when I make a markup error.